# How to find files that contain newline in filename?

Tags: shell, find, patterns

I am trying to find files that have a newline in the filename. But I can't figure out what pattern to use.

The following works, but is not very useful if I want to use it in indented code.

```
find . -name '*
*'
```

I tried these two and they only succeeded in finding filenames that contained the letter *n*:

```
find . -name '*\n*'
find . -name "*\n*"
```

Then I found how to write backslash escape sequences and tried this:

```
find . -name "*$'\n'*"
```

But that doesn't find anything. How should I write the pattern?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In shell scripting, everything is a string. You *do* need to quote the `*` to prevent [filename expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html), but you don't want to put the backslash escape sequence inside double quotes.

You could just concatenate the strings by placing them right after each other.

```
find . -name '*'$'\n''*'
```

But for better readability, you can use [ANSI-C Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) for the whole string.

```
find . -name $'*\n*'
```