# Why can't find -regex match a newline?

Tags: find, regular-expression, filenames, quoting, newlines

Why does this fail?

```
touch "$(printf "a\nb")"; find . -regex './.\n.'
```

I also tried these, none of which work:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.\n.'
find . -regextype posix-awk -regex '.\n.'
find . -regextype posix-basic -regex '.\n.'
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.\n.'
```

The only way it seems to work is (thanks @MichaelMrozek)

```
find . -regex './.'$'\n''.'
```

Which is cumbersome to say the least. So, why do find's regular expressions seem to be unable to deal with `\n`?

---

Update in response to answers so far:

OK, I understand that `\n` is not part of ERE and that was one of my misunderstandings but `find` claims to support `posix-awk` and both `gawk` and `mawk` match `\n` as expected:

```
$ printf "f1l1\nhas newline:f2l1#f1l2 does not:f2l2#" | 
    mawk -F: 'BEGIN{RS="#"}; ($1~/\n/){print $1}' 
f1l1
has newline
```

I don't have a pure `awk` to test with so perhaps POSIX `awk` does not match? Otherwise is `find` not actually implementing `posix-awk` regular expressions?

Comment: Is `find . -name $'*\n*'` cumbersome too?

Comment: Not at all, just irrelevant. I am wondering why `-regex` fails, not [How to find files that contain newline in filename?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118959) which you answered perfectly :).

Comment: After [discussing](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14202844#14202844) this with some other users in chat, it seems likely that the `awk` regex language does not know about `\n` but that the `awk` interpreter does and that's why it matches. Therefore, implementing `awk` regexes as `find` does, would not imply that `\n` should match. Thank you all!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because GNU find doesn't support `\n` as an escape sequence. The regexp `\n` matches the character `n`. GNU find copies the traditional Emacs syntax, which doesn't have this feature either¹.

While GNU find supports other regex syntax, none support backslash-letter or backslash-octal to denote control characters. You need to include the control character literally in the argument.

There are many different regex syntaxes around. Neither POSIX [basic regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03) (BRE) nor [extended regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_04) (ERE) include `\n` or backslash-octal escapes. Both definitions leave the meaning of backslash when not followed by a special character undefined. The utilities [awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_13_04) and [sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html#tag_04_126_13_02) both support `\n` to mean a newline; this is specific to these utilities (and commonplace, but as you see not universal).

From a shell script, you can write

```
find . -regex $'./.\n.'     # ksh/bash/zsh only
find . -regex './.
.'
find . -name '*
*'
```

¹  <sub>Quite logically: for interactive use, you can type any character with `C-q`; for programming use, `\n` exists as part of the string literal syntax.</sub>

Comment: Are basic regular expressions and extended regular expressions not the kind used in `grep`?

Comment: @Melab `grep` uses BRE by default, or ERE with the option `-E`.

Answer (score 8):

You can't match a newline with **'\n'** because it has no special meaning in a regular expression (break line for example), but you can match **the end of line** with **$** regular expression.

Comment: `\n` most certainly does have a meaning in a regex, try `printf "aa\nbb" | perl -ne 'print if /\n/'`, that will only match `aa\n` and skips the `bb` for example. There do seem to be differences in implementation though cause `grep -P` won't match that. But how is `$` relevant here? I want to match a literal newline, `$` matches even in the absence of one: `printf "aa" | grep 'a$'`

Comment: @terdon `\n` has no special meaning, even in Perl regular expressions. It does, however, have special meaning in interpolated perl strings, of which `qr//` is one type. Search for `\n` in `man perlre`...

Comment: @derobert fair point, I expressed myself badly. I meant that `\n` matches newlines in regular expressions. You and babaslovesyou are quite right that it has no _special_ meaning as such, I just mean that is is "matchable" .

Comment: @terdon There are many different regex syntaxes, so claiming that “`\n` has a meaning in a regex” without specifying the regex syntax doesn't make sense.

Comment: @terdon Well, except you're trying to match the character 0x0A (newline), and you're trying to do it with the character sequence 0x5C (backslash) 0x6E (n). Since \n has no special meaning, it tries to match itself. The \ may or may not get stripped out (invalid escape) depending on RE engine, but you're trying to match <NL> vs \n or n, neither matches.

Comment: @terdon in your Perl example, what's actually happening is that the string parsing is turning `\n` into <NL>, before passing it off to the regexp engine. That's a feature of Perl string parsing.

Comment: @derobert Oh. Thanks, had no idea. And +1 to babasloves you.

Answer (score 1):

I think because `find` using `fnmatch`function in standard C library, so if `FNM_NOESCAPE` is not set, a backslash character in pattern followed by any other character will match that second character in string.

```
FNM_NOESCAPE

Don't treat the `\' character specially in patterns. Normally, `\' quotes
the following character, turning off its special meaning (if any) so that it 
matches only itself. When quoting is enabled, the pattern `\?' matches only 
the string `?', because the question mark in the pattern acts like an 
ordinary character. If you use FNM_NOESCAPE, then `\' is an ordinary character.
```

I check with `find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2` and `glibc 2.15`, this option is off. check `line 42` in `fnmatch.h`:

```
#define FNM_NOESCAPE    (1 << 1) /* Backslashes don't quote special chars.  */
```

Comment: `fnmatch` is for `*.txt` type of patterns, not `.*\.txt$` type regexps.