# How can I find and remove files with a carriage return (\r) in the filename?

Tags: regular-expression, filenames, wildcards

Somehow, I seem to have generated files with a carriage return (\r) in the filename:

```
$ ls -1 tri-rods.tm.dat*
tri-rods.tm.dat
'tri-rods.tm.dat'$'\r'
$ ls tri-rods.tm.dat?
'tri-rods.tm.dat'$'\r'
```

I tried find with "\r", but it finds nothing:

```
$ find . -type f -name '*\r'
```

How can I list/find and remove such files?
Adding "?" to the filename works, so I could delete them one by one, but I would prefer a more general way.

Note: I am trying to do this on Windows via Cygwin/git-bash/Windows Subsystem for Linux, so maybe some commands don't work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It finds nothing because the `-name` test takes a shell glob and globs don't know `\r`. Assuming your Cygwin shell supports `$' '` notation, you could do:

```
find . -name '*'$'\r''*'
```

So, to delete, you can do:

```
find . -name '*'$'\r''*' -delete
```

Or, if your `find` doesn't have the `-delete` action, use:

```
find . -name '*'$'\r''*' -exec rm {} +
```

The `-regex` test might seem like the best option, but unfortunately, none of the regex flavors supported by `find` know about backslash-letter
escapes (also see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119007/22222)):

```
$ find . -regextype findutils-default -regex '.*\r.*'
$ find . -regextype ed -regex '.*\r.*'
$ find . -regextype emacs -regex '.*\r.*'
$ find . -regextype gnu-awk -regex '.*\r.*'
$ find . -regextype grep -regex '.*\r.*'
$ find . -regextype posix-awk -regex '.*\r.*'
$ find . -regextype awk -regex '.*\r.*'
$ find . -regextype posix-basic -regex '.*\r.*'
$ find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*\r.*'
$ find . -regextype egrep -regex '.*\r.*'
$ find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*\r.*'
$ find . -regextype posix-minimal-basic -regex '.*\r.*'
$ find . -regextype sed -regex '.*\r.*'
```

Only the first one, with `$'\r'` worked for me:

```
$ find . -name '*'$'\r''*'
./bad?file
```

Comment: @AdminBee not according to GIlles's answer: [Why can't find -regex match a newline?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119007). And I just tried it and can confirm he's right.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Maybe add "find . -name '*'$'\r''*'  -delete -print" for completeness to remove the files (verbosily). I tested and it works on all 3: Cygwin, git-bash and WSL. :)

Comment: Also, any more infos on the $' ' notation? I never heard of it before.

Comment: @KIAaze it's called ["ANSI quoting"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html).Note how you actually have it in the output of `ls` shown in your question.  And good point, I added a note about deleting, thanks.