# POSIX-ly correct way to isolate files with newlines via find?

Tags: command-line, scripting, find, posix, dash

There's a question [How to find files that contain newline in filename?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118959/85039), where the accepted answer handles isolating files with newlines via ANSI-C quoting, and that works fine in `ksh` and `bash`, but how would I handle that in a POSIX shell ? Specifically, I'm using `dash`.

Answer (score 1):

After discussion in comments and looking at the related question referenced in mine, one way use newlines in `-name` is to use literal newline as in:

```sh
$ find -type f -name '*
> *'
```

Another is via command-substitution:

```sh
$ find -name "$(printf '*\n*' )"
./with?newline
$ ls
another execve with?newline
```

But beware that [POSIX definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03), command substitution is performed by
shell with "...removing sequences of one or more  characters at the end
of the substitution". That is something like:

```sh
find -type f -name '*'"$(printf '\n')"'*'
```

fails and passes `**` in argument list instead of `*[newline]*` as one would
think.

The trailing newlines in command substitution can be handled in couple ways as shown at [shell: keep trailing newlines ('\n') in command substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/383217/85039).