# How to find and manipulate files that contain newline in filename?

Tags: find, filenames, newlines

follow up on [How to find files that contain newline in filename?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118959/how-to-find-files-that-contain-newline-in-filename) ,

I need to do some manipulation on the result, for simplicity lets suppose I need to chown them.

Tried following, but does not work:

```
# this is what I usually use, not work
find . -name '*'$'\n''*' -type d |  while read a; do chown www.www "$a"; done

# this is more standard way, still not work
find . -name '*'$'\n''*' -type d | xargs chown www.www '{}'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get `find` to construct the command lines for you, without trying to re-parse lists of files:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name $'*\n*' -type d -exec chown www:www {} +
```

On GNU systems at least, you also need the `LC_ALL=C` to make sure it also finds the files whose name is not valid text in the user's locale.

Comment: can find produce a callable file because I am currently not sure what I want to do with these files? e.g.   find ... > x ; ./x

Comment: Not reliably. Do you really need to make a list of the files before you know what you want to do with them?

Comment: thanks. I found some way to do it with your help. thanks. did `ls -r` and inspected directory by directory (5000-6000 total, 2-3 min) before deleting these.

Comment: One can use `-print0` to generate a list that can be further processed. NUL-delimited records are **the** interchange format used to transfer arbitrary lists of file paths or command line arguments.